# Disable access to activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a settings menu. I want some users to be able to access one particular page on this menu (all users have to log in, some have admin access some only have user access) - only the admin users.

I have figured out how to remove this particular page from the menu if the user is not an admin.

But I consider it good practice to also add a check on the actual activity (java) page as well. In theory, with the link gone in the menu it should be impossible to access this page - but as I said I think it's good practice to add an additional check.

How can I simply "disable" an activity (grey screen, nothing can be touched etc besides the back button) in java code?

Comment: Add a full-screen overlay view that is translucent and clickable (but with no click behavior defined) that you show/hide in your activity?

Comment: Is there no simpler option? It doesn't need to be that fancy - as I said it's just a precaution as in theory it shouldn't be ever visible anyway.

Comment: Override dispatchTouchEvent and return false, preventing all touch events from propagating?

Comment: Ah that sounds good! And the physical back button would still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple method is to override [`dispatchTouchEvent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) in your Activity. For example:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent event) {
    if (shouldBlockTouchEvents) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

This makes sure the default dispatching occurs when you are not deliberately blocking touch events.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if `onCreate()` is called before or after `dispatchTouchEvent()`?

Comment: `dispatchTouchEvent` will only be triggered when a touch event actually occurs; I would think that this must be after `onCreate`. By the way, I don't know if this method will block key events, so users with a keyboard may be able to navigate around the activity still? Not sure on that though.

Comment: @b85411 updated the answer with a sample implementation.